# What is the best YAML parser in elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp, yaml

I want to read config in YAML with elisp code. Searched but didn't find ready-to-use parser in elisp. Did I miss something useful?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if there isn't any then you can call some other parser to read the yaml and have it output a textual lisp representation which you can read with `read`.

Comment: Thanks! It's a good idea. Maybe I can try `pymacs`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - there is a yaml-mode here: https://github.com/yoshiki/yaml-mode - but you want a parser to read the yaml and do what with it?

Comment: I want to read some configuration from YAML files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Three years later, we have [dynamic modules](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dynamic-Modules.html), and [emacs-libyaml](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-libyaml) looks pretty interesting. It uses the dynamic module system to expose the C bindings of [libyaml](https://github.com/yaml/libyaml) in Elisp. I would expect the performance to be fantastic, although I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 5):

Six months later, it appears that the answer is **"there exists no solid easily-available elisp YAML parser."**

If you really want to read a YAML document in elisp and turn it into something that elisp can interact with, you're going to have to put in some gnarly work. The [EmacsWiki YAML page](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/YamlMode) hasn't got much for you, and the canonical [YAML mode](https://github.com/yoshiki/yaml-mode) has syntax hints, but no actual parser. Fortunately someone has [implemented a YAML-parsing web-app](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) that takes YAML and outputs JSON or Python - you could try to get a look under the hood of that and-or use it to check any YAML parser you may write yourself.

Good luck.

Comment: Addendum: see [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2231327/244494) for some getting-started code when writing one's own recursive-descent parser in elisp.

Comment: http://edward.oconnor.cx/2006/03/json.el might also be useful for comparison and ideas.  Obviously, YAML is not JSON, but they certainly have some similarities.

Answer (score 5):

And some months later: I wanted it, so here's how to do it with some help from python:

```
   (defun yaml-parse ()
  "yaml to json to a hashmap of current buffer, with python.

   There is no yaml parser in elisp.
   You need pyYaml and some yaml datatypes like dates are not supported by json."
  (interactive)
  (let ((json-object-type 'hash-table))
    (setq  myyaml (json-read-from-string (shell-command-to-string (concat "python -c 'import sys, yaml, json; json.dump(yaml.load(sys.stdin), sys.stdout, indent=4)' < " (buffer-file-name))))))
  ;; code here
  )
```

It turns the yaml of the current buffer into an elisp hashmap, with the help of `json.el`.

You need python's pyyaml: `pip install PyYaml`.

json.el: http://edward.oconnor.cx/2006/03/json.el

Comment: I mean on one level that's a hack that makes me wince, but on another, I can't bring myself to disrespect "the tool I need doesn't exist, so I'll write it myself." Upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

Three more years later, I'm happy to say that there is now a YAML parser written in Elisp: https://melpa.org/#/yaml

It's API is similar to that of `json-parse-string` in that you can specify it's object and list type.  The following is an example of its usage:

```lisp
(yaml-parse-string "
-
  \"flow in block\"
- >
 Block scalar
- !!map # Block collection
  foo : bar" :object-type 'alist)
;; => ["flow in block" "Block scalar\n" (("foo" . "bar"))]
```

Answer (score 2):

To improve on Ehvince answer using python, a more generic way that allows parsing string, buffers and files:

```
(defun yaml-parse (string)
  "yaml STRING to json to a hashmap of current buffer, with python."
  (interactive)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert string)
    (when (zerop (call-process-region (point-min) (point-max) "python" t t nil "-c" "import sys, yaml, json; json.dump(yaml.load(sys.stdin), sys.stdout)"))
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (json-read))))

(defun yaml-parse-buffer (&optional buffer)
  "Parse yaml BUFFER."
  (with-current-buffer (or buffer (current-buffer))
    (yaml-parse (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max)))))

(defun yaml-parse-file (file)
  "Parse yaml FILE."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents-literally file)
    (yaml-parse (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max)))))
```

You can use the json-* variables to control type mappings.

edit: Added yaml-parse-file

Comment: Trying to use this with a sample yaml file from a symfony project, http://ix.io/2emU/yaml. No go. Debugger entered--Lisp error: (json-number-format 2)
  signal(json-number-format (2))
  json-read-number(t)
  json-read-number()
  json-read()

Comment: @RichieHH: that yaml doesn't look valid to me. What are those \: ?

Comment: part of the key which is a path. Im no expert. YAML files that ship with symfony bundles.